# Get global object (property) name inside a function

Tags: php, object

I have the following object `$db_items` and I pass the sub-object `$db_items->song` as an argument to a function.

```
$db_items = (object) [
    "song"      => (object) [
        "valid"     => false,
        "errors"    => [],
        "inserted"  => false,
    ],
    "album" => (object) [
        "valid"     => false,
        "errors"    => [],
        "inserted"  => false,
    ],
    // ...
];

function log_status($item, $item_name) {
    if ($item->inserted) {
        echo tr([
            td($item_name),
            td("<span class=\"icon-true\">"),
            td(),
        ]);
    } else {
        echo tr([
            td($item_name),
            td("<span class=\"icon-false\">"),
            td(ul($item->errors)),
        ]);
    }
}

log_status($db_items->song, "Song");
log_status($db_items->album, "Album");
```

I want to get rid of the `"Song"` argument in `log_status()`. Is there a way to get the object name of `$db_items->song` -which is `song`- inside the `log_status()` function? Something like:

```
$obj_name = get_obj_name($item); // song, album, or w/e. depends on the passed argument
$item_name = capitalize($obj_name); // Song
```

I've tried `get_class($db_items->song)` but it returns `stdClass`, not `song`.

Comment: `$db_items` is a `stdclass` object and `song` is a property of that object which is itself a `stdclass` object.  Do a `print_r` or `var_dump` to see.  Anything you cast to `(object)` is of `stdclass`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I'm aware of that. Does that mean I can't get `song` as a string?

Comment: See answer.  If I'm off the mark then add more info.  Thanks!

Comment: you could make a class named song.. what other types are there.  You could do it factory method like.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern  Granted it's more work, but it's also more maintainable.

Comment: another option is http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionobject.php, reflection.  But that would be only useful if the to level object only has one property as you won't know the name of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to repeat "song", you could make the function take the whole object as the argument, pass `song` as a separate argument, and have it get the property value dynamically.

```
function log_status($items, $field) {
    $item = $items->$field;
    $item_name = ucfirst($field);
    if ($item->inserted) {
        echo tr([
            td($item_name),
            td("<span class=\"icon-true\">"),
            td(),
        ]);
    } else {
        echo tr([
            td($item_name),
            td("<span class=\"icon-false\">"),
            td(ul($item->errors)),
        ]);
    }
}

log_status($db_items, "song");
log_status($db_items, "album");
```

Comment: This seems to be the most practical approach so far. I'll probably use this.

Comment: Accessing the `$db_items` directly inside the `log_status()` and using only `log_status("song")` now.

Comment: That will work as long as you only have one `$db_items` object that you need to log.

Comment: That's true. This is for a form. Only one thing (lyrics) will be uploaded at a time, so it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

`$db_items` is a `stdclass` object and song is a property of that object which is itself a `stdclass` object. Anything you cast to `(object)` is of type `stdclass`.  So I see two options:

Leave `$db_items` as an array and do:

```
$name = key($db_items);                    // returns "song"
```

Or using the object you have:

```
$name = key(get_object_vars($db_items));   // returns "song"
```

Comment: the third option would be to make the nested stdObject into a class of the type song.  `song => new song($valid, $inserted, $errors )` and then use `get_class`.  Seems like a good fit for the factory method.

Comment: I'll have to access the main object (or the property name `song`) through the passed argument to `log_status()`. `$db_items` doesn't have one property, and I'll be calling `log_status()` multiple times with other arguments. I've updated the question.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix:  Good one.  Post it as an answer.  I figured since they didn't have a song class already that we be overboard.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix:  Check the updated question.  Maybe you can formulate an answer.  I'm headed  out for beer.

Comment: @AbraCadaver - yea it's a lot more work, but depending how many types of thing song could be it would make it more robust and maintainable.  As for posting an answer. It's almost dinner time....  Could also use reflection object.

Answer (score 0):

This is the more proper way to do it.  Using class constants for the name / type makes it easier to remember them and avoids all kinds of nasty error from matching capitalization, spelling etc.  You could even add a bit of validation in the class when setting the type to make sure it is one that is allowable.  Using protected properties instead of public insures encapsulation of your code, which means you can provide a un-changing interface, where the guts of the function dosn't matter to code down the line.

It's more complex, but that's how i roll.....  Besides it gives you a place to expand the functionality of `Item` that keeps it all together and organized.

You could go a few steps further and add a class for the top level object, as well as add sub-classes for  song, album ... setup a few interfaces and then you'd have like a factory pattern, like I mentioned in the comments.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Just depends on how much time, and how maintainable you want it setup.

```
 $db_items = (object) [
    "song" => new Item( Item::SONG, false, false ),
    "album" => new Item( Item::ALBUM, false, false )
    // ...
];

function log_status($item ) {
    if ($item->getInserted()) {
        echo tr([
            td($item->getType()),
            td("<span class=\"icon-true\">"),
            td(),
        ]);
    } else {
        echo tr([
            td($$item->getType()),
            td("<span class=\"icon-false\">"),
            td(ul($item->getErrors())),
        ]);
    }
}


class Item{
    protected $_valid;
    protected $_errors;
    protected $_inserted;
    protected $_type;


    const SONG = 'song'
    const ALBUM = 'album'


    public function __construct( $type, $valid, $inserted, $errors = array()){
        $this->setType( $type );
        $this->setValid( $valid );
        $this->setInserted( $inserted );
        $this->setErrors( $errors );
    }



    public function setValid( $valid ){
        $this->_valid = $valid;
    }


    public function getValid(){
        return $this->_valid;
    }

    public function setType( $type ){


    ....... etc continue on with simpler getter / setters 

}
```

Answer (score -1):

[See the PHP Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), try this example:

```
<?php

$db_items = (object) [
    "song"      => (object) [
        "valid"     => false,
        "errors"    => [],
        "inserted"  => false,
    ],
];


function log_status() {
    global $db_items;
    print_r($db_items->song);
}

log_status();
```

EDITED:

```
$db_items = (object) [
    "song"      => (object) [
        "valid"     => false,
        "errors"    => [],
        "inserted"  => false,
    ],
    "album" => (object) [
        "valid"     => false,
        "errors"    => [],
        "inserted"  => false,
    ]
];


function log_status($db_items, $item) {
    echo $item."<br>";
    print_r($db_items->$item);
}


foreach ($db_items as $key => $item) {
    log_status($db_items, $key);
}
```

Comment: How will he log the album with this code? He wants to be able to log any property, and have it automatically show the property name as well.

Comment: @Barmar The OP edited the question after i answered, that's why this doensn't have sense.

Comment: I looked at the original version, it still doesn't apply. The question was about how to get rid of the `$item_name` argument, not how to get rid of `$item`.

Comment: Look the question "Is there a way to get the object name of $db_items->song -which is song- inside the log_status() function?", "I've tried get_class($db_items->song) but it returns stdClass, not song."

Comment: And how does your solution address that? It doesn't print "Song".

Comment: I just did an example of how to get the object inside the function, make all problem solution for the user is not my responsibility

Comment: He wanted to know how to print the property name without passing it as a separate argument. Your answer doesn't do that at all. He's not having a problem getting the object, just the name.

Comment: I've answered one of the questions in the post, I edited my answer

Comment: "Back in the Stone Age (i.e., before PHP 5), you could only use foreach to iterate over arrays. But as of PHP 5, you can use foreach to iterate over objects, too. By default, iterating over an object will return its visible properties." - [source](http://jontai.me/blog/2012/01/nested-object-iteration-in-php/) - [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php)

Comment: OK, I've deleted that comment. But your `log_status` function still takes the name and item as separate arguments, which is what he's trying to get rid of.

Comment: And your solution not?

Comment: My solution gets rid of the redundancy of specifying "song" in both arguments. So it turns `$db_items->song, "Song"`, into `$db_items, "song"`.

Comment: I just noticed that your latest edit does the same thing, so I've removed my downvote.

Comment: In my last edit i just added a print_r, but ok, my last answer call the function `log_status` inside a loop, if you have more itens in your object, is not necessary call the `log_status` manually all time

Comment: That's useful if you want to log all the properties. There's nothing in the question suggesting that need.